# Is there a way to abort a explorer network file open (without pulling out network)?

Tags: networking, windows-explorer

I was browsing some files with the default explorer on Windows 7 on a **network drive** located in a building on the **other side of the country** when I accidentally tried to open a pdf file of **400+ MB**. The download speed from that network drive is about 300 KB/sec so it would take about 22 minutes to download that file and open it.

Since I didn't want to open that file in the first place I tried the following to abort:

- Opened process explorer and found an instance of Adobe Reader and killed it
- Found the handle to that pdf file in process explorer and closed that handle
- Killed explorer

None of the above seemed to stop the download of that file so I just pulled out my network cable and the download stopped.

In case this happens again and pulling out the cable is not an option, is there a way to abort this download?